# Adjacent bar charts with different scalings

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have this chart created in Excel 2013:

[image]

using this data:

```
                   Last 4 Weeks  Last 12 Months
No. of Accounts              36             186
Net Revenue             149,562       1,176,829
```

I wish to have the line (Net Revenue) as a bar chart next to the already present No. of Accounts bar charts, with the same scalings on the vertical axes.

When I change the `Combo` settings in `Change Chart Type` I get the plot shown below, which is not quite what I want. I wish to have the blue & red bars beside, not above, each other.

[image]

Comment: This seems like a very confusing design for a chart. I prefer your first example - most readers "get" that the line is from a separate series. I would also axis titles to clarify the meaning of each Y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in the data layout of the data source. Put the Net Revenue value in its own column. Insert a gap column. Then select the whole table and insert a clustered column chart. Select the "No. of Accounts" series and send it to the secondary axis. Format both series to a gap width of 0.

[image]